# Does ubuntu tweak add ppa

Tags: ppa

I know downloading softwares from ubuntu tweak usually installs the latest stable, but does it also adds the ppa of the respective software?

Comment: if you need help adding a PPA, you can take a look at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it only installs them. It only adds ppas when you add sources.

Answer (score 5):

The `Application Center` section of Ubuntu Tweak does **not** add PPAs, the `Source Center` section does.